# 'module' object has no attribute 'DescriptorExtractor_create'

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to extract the descriptors using `BRISK`, as follows:

```
cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('BRISK')
```

But, getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DescriptorExtractor_create'
```

Why is that? How can I fix the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are using opencv3. DescriptorExtractor_create is removed in opencv3 along with someother functions.

Comment: its as simple as `cv2.BRISK_create()`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `help` command will clear the air on using the BRISK feature descriptor. To use it type the following in the terminal console:

```
help(cv2.BRISK)
```

In order to obtain the descriptors, there are certain pre-requisites:

1. Create the BRISK object, here `f` is the object of class `BRISK`:

   `f = cv2.BRISK_create()`
2. Find the keypoints for a given image `img` using `detect()` method:

   `keypoints = f.detect(img)`
3. Now using the image and the keypoints you can obtain the descriptors:

   `descriptors = f.compute(img, keypoints)`